# Force text selections (highlights) to be at least one full whitespace-delimited word

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make it so that a div can only be highlighted one word at a time.

So for example, from the above sentence, I could highlight/select `only be highlighted` but not `only be highli`. If I put my mouse at the position of the `highli`, it would either not have selected `highlighted` yet, or it would have selected the entire `highlighted` already.

To clarify, by highlight/select I mean what happens when you click on a word, hold your mouse button down, and drag to another point in the text.

I haven't been able to find any examples of this, but I also feel like I've seen something similar before. Is there a simple way to do this, for example some CSS rule? Or is the only way to roll out some custom javascript handling document selects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word selection can be enforced by wrapping each word into a span element and using user-select:all to force element wide selection for instance

```
    <style>
        .word {
            user-select: all;
        }
    </style>

<span class="word">this</span>
<span class="word">test</span>
<span class="word">is</span>
<span class="word">a</span>
```

Now this can be annoying to do by hand so javascript can come to the rescue for instance this:

```
<style>
    .word {
        -moz-user-select: all;
        -webkit-user-select: all;
        -ms-user-select: all;
        user-select: all;
    }
</style>

<p class="selected-by-word">Hello this is a text where selection should be word-wide.</p>
<p class="selected-by-word">Another text with word-wide selection.</p>

<script>
    let textToSplit = document.getElementsByClassName('selected-by-word')

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(textToSplit, function (anElement) {
        anElement.innerHTML = anElement.innerHTML.replace(/\w+/g, "<span class='word'>$&</span>")
    })
</script>
```

All element having the class selected-by-word will be set for word-wide selection.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! Had to do some weird hacks to get it working with React & Markdown but it works exactly like I wanted it to :)

Comment: @EponymeWeb The getElementsBy* methods return HTMLCollections, which can be difficult to work with. Consider using querySelectorAll instead, which returns a static NodeList - unlike an HTMLCollection, it can be iterated over directly, it won't change while it's being iterated over, and it's much more flexible. `document.querySelectorAll('.selected-by-word').forEach( ...`